# Replicating C struct padding in Java

Tags: java, c, compiler-construction, padding

According to [here](http://c-faq.com/struct/padding.html), the C compiler will pad out values when writing a structure to a binary file. As the example in the link says, when writing a struct like this:

```
struct {
 char c;
 int i;
} a;
```

to a binary file, the compiler will usually leave an unnamed, unused hole between the char and int fields, to ensure that the int field is properly aligned.

How could I to create an exact replica of the binary output file (generated in C), using a different language (in my case, Java)?

Is there an automatic way to apply C padding in Java output? Or do I have to go through compiler documentation to see how it works (the compiler is g++ by the way).

Comment: Its worth noting that char in java is a 16-bit value rather than an 8-bit value as it is in C.  I suggest you use something like ByteBuffer.putInt(0, c & 0xFF); BTW do you know if the data is Big endian or little endian. In C it depends on the architecture of the machine you are running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true not only when writing to files, but also in memory. It is the fact that the struct is padded in memory, that leads to the padding showing up in the file, if the struct is written out byte-by-byte.

It is in general very hard to replicate with certainty the exact padding scheme, although I guess some heuristics would get you quite far. It helps if you have the struct declaration, for analysis.

Typically, fields larger than one char will be aligned so that their starting offset inside the structure is a multiple of their size. This means `short`s will generally be on even offsets (divisible by 2, assuming `sizeof (short) == 2`), while `double`s will be on offsets divisible by 8, and so on.

**UPDATE**: It is for reasons like this (and also reasons having to do with endianness) that it is generally a bad idea to dump whole structs out to files. It's better to do it field-by-field, like so:

```
put_char(out, a.c);
put_int(out, a.i);
```

Assuming the `put`-functions only write the bytes needed for the value, this will emit a padding-less version of the struct to the file, solving the problem. It is also possible to ensure a proper, known, byte-ordering by writing these functions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not in a position to change how the C structs are outputted to files. I was able to get the same output using java by applying simple padding in the form you mentioned. Do you know if there tends to be much variation between how C compilers implement padding??

Comment: It depends mostly on the processor architecture, so the "fun" really starts once you port it to other architectures (we had that recently). Which doesn't mean it's guaranteed to be the same between compilers on the same architecture.

Comment: This talks a bit about struct packing and how and why there is padding applied: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Answer (score 14):

Don't do this, it is brittle and will lead to alignment and endianness bugs.

For external data it is much better to explicitly define the format in terms of bytes and write explicit functions to convert between internal and external format, using shift and masks (not union!).

Comment: XML has a place in this somewhere perhaps?

Comment: @starblue XML has to be a solution to every problem!!1

Comment: @starblue Thanks for the answer. Writing explicit file conversions is not really possible, since there are many C structs that need to be outputted using Java (and the format of these structs may change from time to time). I feel I may have to implement the same form of padding as g++ uses when outputting in Java (I agree with you that this is brittle). The only saving grace is that the platform and compiler will not change, so the endianness bytesize etc. shouldn't change either

Comment: You could also try to make the structure packed by adding __attribute__((__packed__)) . Another solution would be to write a code generator for proper I/O functions.

Comment: @Bombe Did you ever consider a 10 megapixel HDR image in xml LOL. A good file format should consider the same endiannes as the majority of the target processors. This is also true for the padding rules. A scanline in a windows bitmap always starts on a 4 byte boundary. Being binary compatible the entire way will speed things up.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an automatic way to apply C
>   padding in Java output? Or do I have
>   to go through compiler documentation
>   to see how it works (the compiler is
>   g++ by the way).

Neither. Instead, you explicitly specify a data/communication format and implement that specification, rather than relying on implementation details of the C compiler. You won't even get the same output from different C compilers.

Answer (score 4):

For interoperability, look at the ByteBuffer class.

Essentially, you create a buffer of a certain size, put() variables of different types at different positions, and then call array() at the end to retrieve the "raw" data representation:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
bb.put(0, someChar);
bb.put(4, someInteger);
byte[] rawBytes = bb.array();
```

But it's up to you to work out where to put padding-- i.e. how many bytes to skip between positions.

For reading data written from C, then you generally *wrap()* a ByteBuffer around some byte array that you've read from a file.

In case it's helpful, I've written more on [ByteBuffer](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_byte_order.shtml).

Comment: Yes, I have been using ByteBuffer. The issue I am really having is in finding out how much to pad the bytes when writing/reading..

Answer (score 2):

A handy way of reading/writing C structs in Java is to use the javolution Struct class (see http://www.javolution.org).  This won't help you with automatically padding/aligning your data, but it does make working with raw data held in a ByteBuffer much more convenient.  If you're not familiar with javolution, it's well worth a look as there's lots of other cool stuff in there too.

Answer (score 1):

This hole is configurable, compiler has switches to align structs by 1/2/4/8 bytes.

So the first question is: Which alignment exactly do you want to simulate?

Answer (score 1):

With Java, the size of data types are defined by the language specification. For example, a `byte` type is 1 byte, `short` is 2 bytes, and so on. This is unlike C, where the size of each type is architecture-dependent.

Therefore, it would be important to know how the binary file is formatted in order to be able to read the file into Java.

It may be necessary to take steps in order to be certain that fields are a specific size, to account for differences in the compiler or architecture. The mention of alignment seem to suggest that the output file will depend on the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

you could try [preon](http://preon.sourceforge.net/):

> Preon is a java library for building codecs for bitstream-compressed data in a 
>   declarative (annotation based) way. Think JAXB or Hibernate, but then for binary 
>   encoded data.

it can handle Big/Little endian binary data, alignment (padding) and various numeric types along other features. It is a very nice library, I like it very much

my 0.02$

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're saying that you don't control the output of the C program. You have to take it as given.

So do you have to read this file for some specific set of structures, or do you have to solve this in a general case? I mean, is the problem that someone said, "Here's the file created by program X, you have to read it in Java"? Or do they expect your Java program to read the C source code, find the structure definition, and then read it in Java?

If you've got a specific file to read, the problem isn't really very difficult. Either by reviewing the C compiler specifications or by studying example files, figure out where the padding is. Then on the Java side, read the file as a stream of bytes, and build the values you know are coming. Basically I'd write a set of functions to read the required number of bytes from an InputStream and turn them into the appropriate data type. Like:

```
int readInt(InputStream is,int len)
  throws PrematureEndOfDataException
{
  int n=0;
  while (len-->0)
  {
    int i=is.read();
    if (i==-1)
      throw new PrematureEndOfDataException();
    byte b=(byte) i;
    n=(n<<8)+b;
  }
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can alter the packing on the c side to ensure that no padding is used, or alternatively you can look at the resultant file format in a hex editor to allow you to write a parser in Java that ignores bytes that are padding.